# Quando entrar na Exception, chamar o método incial novamente para mais uma tentativa sem entrar em loop infinito

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp-net-core

Bom dia!
Possuo um método para atualização de produtos/Sku em uma api, e quando for atualizar um registro preciso forçar uma nova tentativa de execução do mesmo método quando cair em uma exception de TooManyRequest.

Exemplo:

No metodo UpdateProductSku abaixo, é tentado atualizar o registro no trecho do "try", caso ocorra uma exception por "TooManyRequest", é feito dentro do Catch, uma verificação para uma nova tentativa chamando o método novamente.

```
        public async Task<bool> UpdateProductSku(string domain, ProductSku sku)
        {
        var saleschannel = await this._saleschannel.GetSalesChannel(domain, EnMarketPlaceType.MagazineLuiza);
        try
        {
            await this._magaluprovider.UpdateProductSku(saleschannel, sku);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex is MagaluException magaluException)
            {
                    if (magaluException.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.TooManyRequests)
                    {
                        int attempt = 0;
                        if (attempt < 1)
                        {
                            attempt++;
                            await UpdateProductSku(domain, sku);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            await ValidateResponseError429(magaluException.StatusCode, magaluException.Message);
                        }
                    }
            }

            throw;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Como posso tratar essa nova tentativa, sem que entre em loop infinito, que é o que está ocorrendo no código acima.

Answer (score 1):

Você procura por algo que te ajude a implementar políticas de resiliência.

Atualmente, a [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly#retry) é uma das bibliotecas mais usadas pela comunidade. Aplicá-la ao seu código é simples, você só precisa criar uma política e usar o método `Execute` da política para executar o seu código.

```cs
using Polly;
using System.Net;

var políticaRetentativa = Policy
  .Handle<MagaluException>(e => e.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.TooManyRequests)
  .Retry(1);

políticaRetentativa.Execute(() => 
{
    // Lógica da chamada HTTP
});
```

Se você estiver usando ASP.NET Core, é possível adicionar as políticas direto na injeção do `HttpClient`. Você pode ver mais na [documentação](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly#using-polly-with-httpclient-factory-from-aspnet-core-21).

Answer (score 0):

Mudei o número de tentativas para ser passado como um parâmetro. O código anterior estava com a variável attempt sendo inicializada com 0 (zero) toda vez que ocorria a Exception.

```
        public async Task<bool> UpdateProductSku(string domain, ProductSku sku, int attempt = 0)
    {
        var saleschannel = await this._saleschannel.GetSalesChannel(domain, EnMarketPlaceType.MagazineLuiza);
        try
        {
            await this._magaluprovider.UpdateProductSku(saleschannel, sku);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex is MagaluException magaluException)
            {
                if (magaluException.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.TooManyRequests)
                {
                    //int attempt = 0;
                    if (attempt < 1)
                    {
                        attempt++;
                        await UpdateProductSku(domain, sku, attempt);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await ValidateResponseError429(magaluException.StatusCode, magaluException.Message);
                    }
                }
            }

            throw;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).